# How to remove default input text

Tags: jquery

I have:

```
<input type="text" id="nome" value="Nome..." />
```

I have to remove it, **one time**....when the focus will be on the input text.

I have to use jquery...

Thank you

Answer (score 9):

**Simple answer:**

```
$('#nome').focus(function() {
    $(this).val('');
});
```

**Elaborated answer:**

Although the above should work, it is not really friendly, since it will clear the field after you typed something in it as well. I usually do something like this:

```
$('input.clearonfocus').focus(function() {
    if (!$(this).data('originalValue')) {
        $(this).data('originalValue', $(this).val());
    }
    if ($(this).val() == $(this).data('originalValue')) {
        $(this).val('');
    }
}).blur(function(){
    if ($(this).val() == '') {
        $(this).val($(this).data('originalValue'));
    }
});
```

**The *advantage* of the latter example is that it removes the value on focus, but does it *only when you did not change the value*.**

Comment: Only when you **didn't** change the value :)

Answer (score 0):

Also note that you have new *placeholder* attribute for this purpose in HTML5. So in HTML5 enabled browsers this should be as easy as:
    *<input type="text" placeholder="Nome..." />*

You can check following link which enables you using the *placeholder* attributes even in browsers which are not HTML5 enabled:

[Using HTML5 placeholder attribute in browser which don't support it via jQuery](http://web.enavu.com/design/css/use-html5-placeholder-input-attribute-today-using-jquery/)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need this plugin: http://www.aaronvanderzwan.com/focusmagic/

> This plugin is meant to expedite the
>   basic process of making form fields
>   empty on focus and refill on blur,
>   depending on a few specs. The three
>   different scenarios that I have built
>   for are represented here.
>
> Scenario 1 This is represented by the
>   first three fields on the right. This
>   scenario is the normal one. We want
>   the label to become a watermark.
>
> Scenario 2 Often times with forms
>   there is validation server side. This
>   scenario loads a server sent value.
>   This plugin doesn't do anything and
>   lets the value set by the server work
>   by it's self.
>
> Scenario 3 Every once in a while we
>   want an exception. Well scenario three
>   (the 'ignored' textarea on the right)
>   displays how this works. To not use
>   the plugin on a specific label /
>   field, simply add an 'ignore' class to
>   it.

Comment: it does what you want...and is very simple.